# Const Class Member Copy Constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, copy

```
#include "booking.h"
#include <iostream>
booking::booking (  const std::string p_title,  const std::string p_notice,  const category p_category,  const person p_person,  const booking::Type p_type,  const double p_value ) :
m_type{ p_type },
m_title{ p_title },
m_notice{ p_notice },
m_person{ p_person },
m_category{ p_category },
m_value { p_value }
{
    std::cout << "Booking was created" << std::endl; // Debug Message
}
```

These are the files (everything thats necessary to know in my opinion)

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "person.h"
#include "category.h"
class booking
{
public:
    enum Type { TYPE_REVENUE, TYPE_EXPENDITURE };
    booking ( const std::string p_title, const std::string p_notice, const category p_category, const person p_person, const booking::Type p_type, const double p_value ); //Basic Constructor
    ~booking();
    Type GetType ( );
    std::string GetTitle ( );
    std::string GetNotice ( );
    category GetCategory ( );
    double GetValue ( );

private:
     Type m_type;
     std::string m_title;
     std::string m_notice;
     category m_category;
     person m_person;
     double m_value;

};
```

If i put one of the class members (like m_type or the double value, it doesnt matter which) to const, it throws following error:

> Fehler    1   error C2280: `booking &booking::operator =(const booking &)` : attempting to reference a deleted function   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2013 CTP\include\utility   53

I dont get why the compiler complains about the copy constructor and whats basicly the matter.

Comment: Pass strings by const reference, and probably your person and category too.

Comment: Apart from rare occasions, I never make a member variable const. Instead I make the object itself const, if I don't want it to change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you declare a `const` member, the compiler does not generate a default **assignment operator** (it has no clue what to do with this member during assignment, after all, it is const ?), you will have to write the assignment operator yourself.

**Note:**

- pass you parameters by reference to const.

Comment: _"you will have to write the assignment operator yourself"_ Most likely, such an operator would be extremely surprising and instead should not exist.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: True, it's unlikely an assignment operator will be meaningful for a class with a `const` data member, but there are some cases. For example, indexing a `std::vector<bool>` produces a proxy that can be assigned to in order to change the bitset state. I don't know if it has any `const` member, but it could have. And still be meaningful.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Sure, it's possible, which is why I said "most likely". Though holding up `std::vector<bool>` as an example of class design is not recommended :P

Answer (score 6):

You can't (reasonably) assign to an object of a class that has `const` members.

That's why you get an error about the *copy assignment operator*.

You're not getting a complaint about the copy constructor.

---

In other news:

- In C++ ALL UPPERCASE names are a convention for macros. If they're used for anything else (e.g. constants, as in Java) then you increase the risk of name collisions and inadvertent text replacement. Besides it's an eyesore, read by many as extra heavy emphasis. Java doesn't have a preprocessor. C++ does have one.
- It's a good idea to pass non-basic-type arguments in general as reference to `const` (you only added `const`). There are some extra considerations for large arguments that are copied. In C++11 these are best passed by value and moved.
- Simple "getter" member function should be declared `const` so that they can be called on a `const` object.

Regarding the Java-inspired `Get` prefixes, consider `GetSin(u)+GetCos(v)` versus `sin(u)+cos(v)`. In Java a `Get` prefix can have some value for tools that use introspection. Java has introspection. C++ doesn't have instrospection. The conventions employed should better be adapted to the language used.

Comment: Meh, I use all caps for enum keys and for non-macro `const`. It's a matter of taste. I admit it's a bit silly due to the collision risk.

Comment: _"In C++11 these are best passed by value and moved."_ Only when you don't need the original any more... If the function is only going to observe the value, passing by const reference is still vastly preferable overall.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: There are some valid reasons for using ref-to-const formal argument type also for a large argument that's going to be copied. However, “Only [pass by value and move] when you don't need the original any more” is not such a reason. Because it doesn't make sense (there is no effect on the actual argument), sorry.

Comment: It most certainly _is_ such a reason, because if you _do_ still need the original then passing by value and move completely breaks your program. Sorry.

Comment: @MikeMB: Oh, my, goodness. No, I was certainly not aware. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 5):

`operator=` is not the copy-constructor, it is the *assignment operator*.

`const` objects cannot be updated, so in your assignment operator you cannot modify the object.

If you don't declare your own assignment operator, the compiler generates one for you which does member-wise copy. But if there is a const member, this doesn't work, so it can't generate the assignment operator after all. (In C++11 this is called having a *deleted* assignment operator).

Finally, if you have some code that tries to use the assignment operator, then you get this error about attempting to use the deleted assignment operator.  Some of the standard library containers or algorithms require the assignment operator to be present. You didn't show all your code but somewhere you will have tried to perform an operation that requires assignment.

Answer (score 4):

referring this [thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/4733/), as to the copy constructor with const members,

the general form of the copy constructor is,

```
class Foo {
Foo( const Foo& f ) :
  mem1( f.mem1 ), mem2( f.mem2 ) /* etc */
{}
};
```

where mem1 and mem2 are data members of Foo, which can be const
members, non-const members, const references or non-const references.